# I18n not working after deployment on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, internationalization, http-status-code-404, netlify

I'm encountering an issue with my React application's internationalization (i18n) after deploying it on Netlify. The i18n library is not loading translation files correctly.Everything works locally, but i18n doesn't work in deployment.It gives these errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()   /locales/en-US/translation.json:1 .

My i18n configuration is like that :

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import HttpApi from "i18next-http-backend";
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    order: ["localstorage"],
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json",
    }
  });
```

Checked the file structure of i18n to confirm that the translation files are in the expected directories.